# Process field before database insert / update

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django model with a text field. I'm using a rich text editor (nicEdit) on the admin site to allow the client to easily enter markup into the field. I'd like to process the contents of the field and perform a few actions before anything is inserted into the database.

For example, I want to strip junk generated by MS Word, font tags, etc. I hope this part should be easy, but I'm not sure what to override or hook to get this working.

I also want to detect remotely-linked images, download a local copy to MEDIA_ROOT, and relink the img src to the local image. I'm not quite sure how to go about fetching the remote image; I thought `django.Storage` might help but it looks like it's unable to fetch content from a remote URL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripping the junk and such should be done with a custom formfield.

Downloading the images... there are multiple ways to fix that problem.

- If you choose to store the image location and original location in the database, than you should do it with a pre-save signal.
- If you choose to store the images locally directly, than you can make it part of the formfield aswell. Simply download all remote images and replace the urls with a local url.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I haven't messed with forms at all yet, let alone creating custom form fields. If you could post a short example I'd be eternally grateful. Also, _how_ do I download the images?

Comment: @no: in that case, why don't you try something like this: http://code.google.com/p/django-richtext/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the source. The django-photologue project linked from there looks good too. This still doesn't solve the image downloading problem, but it looks like urllib can cover that.

Comment: re: django-richtext: how the heck do you install this thing?

Comment: Installing should be as simple as using `content = AdminRichTextField()` in your model and/or `message = RichTextField()` in your form.

Comment: It was... Somehow comments starting at the beginning of the line are significant in python, aren't they? They delineate modules or something? I think that's what was messing me up before.

Comment: Comments have no real importance in Python but they can be used for documentation (i.e. `help(function)` will return it's docoumentation) and testing with `doctests`. However, whitespace is very important in Python. So if you accidently mix tabs and spaces or use uneven indenting than your code can do unexpected things.

Comment: hmm, maybe some tabs snuck in there. looking at this now: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Answer (score 9):

To manipulate data in your model before saving it, use the `save()` method like:

```py
def save(self):
  self.NameOfTextField = myCustomCleanFunction(self.NameOfTextField)
  super(YourModelName, self).save()
```

Nothing will be saved until `super(modelname, self).save()` is executed.

If you want the possibility of raising some type of error instead of just processing it silently, you'll probably want to use the `clean()` method with `raise ValidationError()`.

Downloading remote content is a new one for me, so I can't help you there. You might have to look past Django and find Python functions to do the job.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for. I'll try it later and report back.

Comment: It works, but it's not reusable, unless there's something I can replace `YourModelName` with in an abstract base class to get the right class.

Comment: @no: You can easily make it reusable by adding that code in a separate method with a `signal` instead of overwriting the `save` code.

Comment: So if I don't override save, how can they save it from the admin interface?

Comment: @no: You can use the pre_save signal instead of overriding `save`. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save

Answer (score 0):

this work for me...

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   text = model.TextField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text= myCustomCleanFunction(self.text)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if the process is simple you can put the code in the save function instead of the function call `myCustomCleanFunction(self.text)`